# for loop wont continue

Tags: php, variables, if-statement, for-loop

I have a code here that should continue up to 670

```
$pages = 670;
$part1 = 16;
$part2 = 31;
$part3 = 99;    
for ($i=1; $i<=$pages; $i++){
    if ($i == 1){
       echo "1st part, ";
    }elseif ($i == $part1){
       $pages = $part2 - $part1;
       echo $pages . ", ";
       $pages = 0;
    }elseif ($i == $part2){
       $pages = $part3 - $part2;
       echo $pages . ", ";
       $pages = 0;
    }
  echo "<strong>" . $i . "</strong>" . ", ";
}
```

But when i open the php the result will be:

- 1st part 
  **1**, **2**, **3**, **4**, **5**, **6**, **7**, **8**, **9**, **10**, **11**, **12**, **13**, **14**, **15**, 15, **16**,

What is the problem so my for loop will continue?

*Note: part2 - part1 = 15, part 3 - part2 = 68.

Answer (score 3):

The line : `$pages = 0;` is the problem. Change the variable name.

Answer (score 3):

Once `$i` hits 16, you set `$pages = 0;`, so the condition `$i <= $pages` becomes false and the loop stops.

Answer (score 1):

You change

```
$pages = 0;
```

And that's why it won't continue, because it's not 670 anymore.

Answer (score 0):

In the first else if you check if `$i == $part1`

Example:

```
$i = 16;

elseif($i == $part1) // true
{
    $pages = $part2 - $part1; // $pages = 15 -> for loop = for($i <= $pages) will break cause $i = 16
    echo $pages . ", ";
    $pages = 0; // -> again forloop, $i is bigger then pages cause pages = 0;
}
```

Look to your variables, maybe you can explain us what you want to do, then we can help you to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you trying to achieve? At the moment, when you execute the first elseif part, i.e. $i == $part1, you reset $pages to 0. Thus, you print the non-bold 15, and then in bold the value 16. This means at this point $i == 16 and $pages == 0. Therefore you will exit the loop; The condition  $i<=$pages will evaluate to false.

If you simply want to count to 670, why don't you remove both, the $pages = $part2 - $part1; and $pages = 0; statements? You can just use echo ($part2 - $part1) . ", "; directly

The same applies to the second elseif block